# glibc version older than gcc version and -Wl,-rpath not work

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, glibc

i'm working on a cross compile for armhf,compile process just goes well,but the GLIBC version is old ,**./libc.so.6** shows it was compiled by gcc 4.6.3,unfortunately i can't find this old version on apt-get.so i 've tried to relocate the lib path by using follow LDFLAG option.

> -Wl,-rpath,/boxer/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker,/boxer/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3

and deployed the corresponding library to /boxer/lib,but the problem not solve,and **./ld-linux-armhf.so.3 --list** shows that the ld was linked to correct place,but,as u can see below, the rest not.

```
root@cubieboard2:/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf# ./ld-linux-armhf.so.3 --list /boxer/frida-server
/boxer/frida-server: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /boxer/frida-server)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libresolv.so.2 (0xb6f7a000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0xb6f6e000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6f53000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e6f000)
        /boxer/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 => ./ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f9e000)
```

any suggestion?thanks.

**Update:**

Here is the **`LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1`** option result,seem like the same as above

```
root@cubieboard2:/boxer# LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /boxer/frida-server
/boxer/frida-server: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /boxer/frida-server)
        libresolv.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libresolv.so.2 (0xb6f10000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2 (0xb6f05000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6eea000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6 (0xb6e06000)
        /boxer/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f28000)
root@cubieboard2:/boxer#
```

the ld-linux has the right place to go,but the others still on the old way...

Here is another program that i compiled earlier using QT,with the rpath LDFLAG:

> QMAKE_LFLAGS +=-Wl,-rpath,/boxer/lib
>   -Wl,--dynamic-linker,/boxer/lib/ld-linux.so.3

yes i was follow [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) and it works fine(Thanks,big help :-) ),**`LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1`** result:

```
# LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /boxer/Boxer
        libdl.so.2 => /boxer/lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb6efb000)
        libQt5Widgets.so.5 => /boxer/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5 (0xb69b9000)
        libQt5Gui.so.5 => /boxer/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0xb655f000)
        libQt5Network.so.5 => /boxer/lib/libQt5Network.so.5 (0xb646f000)
        libQt5Core.so.5 => /boxer/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0xb5f50000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /boxer/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb5f27000)
        libstdc++.so.6 => /boxer/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xb5ddc000)
        libm.so.6 => /boxer/lib/libm.so.6 (0xb5d2a000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /boxer/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xb5cfa000)
        libc.so.6 => /boxer/lib/libc.so.6 (0xb5bb5000)
        /boxer/lib/ld-linux.so.3 (0xb6f0e000)
        librt.so.1 => /boxer/lib/librt.so.1 (0xb5b9e000)
```

we can see everything goes well include the libc,what's the different?

Answer (score 0):

> GLIBC version is old ,./libc.so.6 shows it was compiled by gcc 4.6.3, unfortunately i can't find this old version on apt-get.

Note that the version of GLIBC has *very little* to do with the version of GCC it was compiled with. Newer versions of GLIBC do require newer version of GCC to build them, but the relationship is far from one-to-one.

> deployed the corresponding library to /boxer/lib,but the problem not solve,and ./ld-linux-armhf.so.3 --list shows that the ld was linked to correct place,but,as u can see below, the rest not.

You'll need to build GLIBC with `--prefix=/boxer` for `ld-linux` to look in alternate location. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617).

**Update:**

I misinterpreted your question. This command:

```
./ld-linux-armhf.so.3 --list /boxer/frida-server
```

does *not* tell you what you want to know (which libraries would be loaded at runtime), because it doesn't pay attention to the `RPATH` compiled into the application (it only uses paths compiled into `ld-linux` itself).

Instead, you want:

```
LD_TRACE_LOADED_OBJECTS=1 /boxer/frida-server
```

which shows what libraries would *actually* be loaded.

Comment: the link u mentioned have already been read and i tried it on my case as you can see ,but it doesn't work for me,someting wrong in my compile options?and i will not build GLIBC by my self,just use compilier's libraries that i'm using.

Comment: as u said on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host/851229#851229),the option`-Wl,-rpath,/boxer/lib -Wl,--dynamic-linker,/boxer/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` means make the runtime loader search for libraries in **/boxer/lib** and "bake" **/boxer/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3** to correct ld-linux.so.2 into the application.am i misunderstand this?